# Call the before unload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtmlx

I have a dhtmlxwindow in my application. When the user makes changes and then presses on Backspace, I want this dialog to be shown:

https://cube3x.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/confirm-navigation.png

This is the code for loading the dhtmlx window:

```
var win = dhxWins.createWindow("selectIt", 10, 10, 940, 550);
        win.setText(some_text);
        win.denyResize();
        win.denyPark();
        win.setModal(true);
        win.center();
        win.attachURL("/sdgdsggh/SelectIt");
        win.attachEvent("onClose", function (win) {
            return true;
        });
//This is what I tried
        win.attachEvent("beforeunload", function (win) {
            debugger;
            return true;
        });
```

I know I should call the before unload event, but how do I do that?

Comment: retrun string from `beforeunload` event (don't bind unload event which has really different behaviour across browsers). FYI, Firefox could not show any custom string (not sure about lastest FF version)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the beforeunload , the event is automatically fired by browser when your window unloads

you can use  addEventListener on the window object.

**

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload',
            function(){console.log(unloaded)});
```

**